# How do I express total surprise or perplexity when asking a question?

Tags: idiom, interrogative

Are there conventional expressions in Latin to strengthen the question, showing total surprise or perplexity? How do you say, for example, "What the heck...?" or "Why on earth...?" in Latin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way of expressing surprise is to add the word *nam* to a question, which seems to add a sense of "... and I really have no idea what the answer is". [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnam) (section III of the entry) describe this use of *nam* as "expressing wonder or emotion in the questioner". *Nam* often follows the interrogative pronoun *quis* and is written together as one word, [*quisnam*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquisnam), which can be translated as e.g. "who in the world?" or "I wonder who?":

> Quidnam id est?
>   *What in the world is that? I wonder what that is?*

Answer (score 11):

It's often difficult to match idioms exactly between languages, but in at least one case you mention Latin has an almost exact equivalent: **Ubi terrarum...?**

> non edepol nunc **ubi terrarum** sim scio (Plautus, *Amphitruo* 336)
>   *Now I don't have a clue **where on earth** I am.*
>
> Quid istúc est? aut **ubi** istúc est **terrarum** loci? (Plautus, *Asinaria* 32)
>   *What is this? And **where on earth** is this place*?

Obviously, it is also possible to pair adverbs (**Quid nunc? Quid iam?** -What now? **Cur edepol, mehercle?** -Why in heaven's name?) or insults (**Quid, insane, rogites...? Quid, verbero?**) to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answers already given, **tandem** after interrogative might be added for the sake of emphasis, like *nam* (in TKR's answer), but might be [even stronger](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=2rsTwKhI59cC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=pray%20tandem%20latin&source=bl&ots=usWsbFaaT0&sig=ACfU3U3bUvqprRuU1skufulAJSZtaVjdSQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizp9XPqP7pAhUPNOwKHa4tCB4Q6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=pray%20tandem%20latin&f=false).

According to [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=tandem) (I.B) it has the flavor of adverbial *pray* in English, so it not necessarily expresses "total surprise or perplexity" so-strong as in the sense of "what the heck?" (though, it might), but it clearly strengthening the question.

[This source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=pL80AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA291&dq=%22quid%20tandem%22%20quid%20tandem,%20what%20in%20the%20world&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj96nruP7pAhVBxaYKHWfqCOIQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22quid%20tandem%22%20quid%20tandem%2C%20what%20in%20the%20world&f=false), while explaining *tandem*, also mentions **dii boni**, that might be translated as "for heaven's sake":

> quamquam **o dii boni!** quid est in hominis vita diu?