# Can we finally know the difference between these words?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, synonyms

There seem to be four different Latin words, all of which are common, and all of which seem to mean exactly the same thing, "finally":

- tandem
- denique
- demum
- postremo

Is there any difference between these words, or are they all interchangeable? Seems kind of ridiculous to have have four adverbs all meaning the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say, in a sense, *tandem* is little different from the rest, as *tandem* tends to imply pressure that was accumulating and being released, or something that was expected and *finally* happens (i.e. Not necessarily after sequence of events). Thus, you can see *tandem* used to [intensify a question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/how-do-i-express-total-surprise-or-perplexity-when-asking-a-question/14046#14046) to indicate asker's stress. Practically speaking, in the title of this question: "Can we *finally* know the difference between these words?" I would gladly translate *finally* as *tandem* - and it seems others are less appropriate.

At any case, they are all indeed very close. To reveal the nuances, it is adviced to consult some good books of Latin Synonyms like this of [Dumesnil](https://books.google.com/books?id=pWQZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=DEMUM,%20at%20length,%20after%20a%20long%20time&source=bl&ots=pbWFh6-GQI&sig=ACfU3U000UzGLoOgxrO-uCO7BeB1U428Xg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_kajerdTsAhUOyoUKHRZMDG8Q6AEwA3oECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=DEMUM%2C%20at%20length%2C%20after%20a%20long%20time&f=false), that I'll quote here:

> **DEMUM**, at length, after a long time. *Nunc demùm litteris tuis rescribo*. (Cic.) *Demùm* is also taken in a sense analogous to *solùm*, *tantùm*, only. *Ea demùm magna voluptas est, æqualem ac parem verbis vitam agere*. (Cic.) —**DENIQUE**, in fine, is placed at the end of a long enumeration. *Non avaritia, non libido, non amœnitas, non nobilitas urbis, non deniquè labor, &c*. (Cic.) —**TANDEM**, when a thing has been a great while longed-after. *Tandem progreditur magnâ stipante catervâ*. (Virg.) *Ibis tandem aliquandò, quò te, &c.* (Cic.)